# How to require "__base__/bar" in Lua?

Tags: lua

I have a file `foo.lua` that I'm running with `lua foo.lua`. The file requires a package `__base__/bar` like so:

```lua
-- foo.bar
require("__base__/bar")

print("foo")
```

File `bar.lua` is in `C:\Temp`, which is also the `__base__` path.

**How do I make the require look into `C:\Temp` whenever a `require` imports from `__base__`?** I cannot change that that line: `require("__base__/bar")`!

I tried the following in `foo.lua` which does print the correct path, but somehow it still does not require:

```lua
-- foo.bar
local function custom_loader(name)
    -- Replace "__base__" with "C:/Temp" in the module name
    local modified_name = name:gsub("__base__", "C:/Temp")
    -- Attempt to load the module using the modified name
    print("DEBUG", package.searchpath(modified_name, "?.lua"))
    return package.searchpath(modified_name, "?.lua")
end
table.insert(package.searchers, custom_loader)

require("__base__/bar")

print("foo")
```

```
PS C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset> .\lua52.exe .\foo.lua
DEBUG:  C:/Temp/bar.lua
C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset\lua52.exe: .\foo.lua:10: module '__base__/bar' not found:
        no field package.preload['__base__/bar']
        no file 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset\lua\__base__/bar.lua'
        no file 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset\lua\__base__/bar\init.lua'
        no file 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset\__base__/bar.lua'
        no file 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset\__base__/bar\init.lua'
        no file '.\__base__/bar.lua'
        no file 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset\__base__/bar.dll'
        no file 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset\loadall.dll'
        no file '.\__base__/bar.dll'
        no file 'C:\Users\Daniel\Documents\source\asset\__base__/bar52.dll'
        no file '.\__base__/bar52.dll'C:/Temp/bar.lua
stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .\foo.lua:10: in main chunk
        [C]: in ?
```

Comment: I assume you can monkeypatch `require()`? If so, would a `_require = require`/`require = fucntion() ... end` solution work for you?

Comment: I think that would Work. Could you pleased Post a complete answer,because the comment alone doesnt Help me solve my Problem.

Comment: You don't need a new loader. 1) Create `C:\Temp\__base__` folder and put `bar.lua` there. 2) Add `C:\Temp\?.lua;` to `package.path` variable. 3) Invoke `require("__base__.bar")`

Comment: @ESkri Thanks, but creating a folder `__base__` cannot be part of the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your idea is correct, but you incorrectly defined the searcher, as stated in the [document](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-package.searchers)

> The function can **return another function** (the module loader) plus an extra value that will be passed to that loader, **or a string** explaining why it did not find that module (or nil if it has nothing to say).

Since you returned a string, it is equivalent to telling `require` that your search failed. Here's a working version:

```
local function custom_loader(name)
    return function(name)
        local modified_name = name:gsub("__base__", "C:/Temp")
        modified_name = package.searchpath(modified_name, "?.lua")
        package.loaded[name] = dofile(modified_name)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `require` is just a variable and therefore can be reassigned just like any other variables, I *think* you can monkeypatch it as follow:

```lua
local _require = require

require = function(name)
    local modified_name = name:gsub('__base__', 'C:/Temp')
    print(modified_name)

    return _require(modified_name)
end
```

Try it:

```lua
local bar = require('__base__/bar')
print(bar)

-- 'C:/Temp/bar'
-- table: 0x1ffffff
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailled write-up. I decided to accept shingo's, because it seems a more conventional way of doing it.